# How to find the mean of the value at an index in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a numpy array as show below and I want to calculate the mean of values at index 0 of each array (1,1,1) or index 3 (4,5,6). Is there a numpy function that can solve this? I tried numpy.mean, but it does not solve the issue.

```
[[1,2,3,4],
[1,2,3,5],  --> = [(1+1+1)/3, (2+2+2)/3, (3+3+3)/3, (4+5+6)/3] --> [1,2,3,5] 
[1,2,3,6]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a = array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 6]])

np.mean(a, axis=0)

-> array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  5.])
```

The parameter `axis` lets you select the direction across which you want to calculate the mean.

Comment: Please think twice before answering questions that are blatant duplicates. Vote to close, when you have the privilege to. Sorry the advice comes this late, but better late than never.

Answer (score 2):

Take the mean along the first axis - *axis 0*:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],
...               [1,2,3,5],  
...               [1,2,3,6]])
>>> a.mean(axis=0)
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  5.])
```

Comment: Sorry, about what happened here. After many months and answers as a seasoned user here I'd like to say that neither the question nor its answers deserve the upvotes it's gotten. This is a blatant duplicate.